# Hide element in mobile app but not in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, mobile-application, mobile-browser

I'm using a cloud application to build an intranet. One of the widgets uses HTML5 geolocation. The widget works as expected on desktop and mobile browsers. 
However, the platform also has an app which is basically just a browser; on the app (smartphone and tablet), the widget does display anything.

I'm wondering if there's a media query that I can use to hide the widget only when using the app. I'd like it to still appear on mobile browsers though. If it's not possible through CSS, maybe with jQuery?